# Java 8 stream, groupBy and method invocation

Tags: java, mapreduce, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code:

```
ConcurrentMap<String, Zipper> zippers = list.parallelStream()
    .map( f -> {return new Facet( f ) ; } )
    .collect( 
        Collectors.groupingByConcurrent( Facet::getZip,
        Collector.of( Zipper::new, 
                  Zipper::accept, 
                  (a,b)-> {a.combine(b); return a; } )
        )) ;

for ( String key: zippers.keySet() )
{
    zippers.get( key ).zip() ;
}
```

Given that I only need the Zipper objects to invoke the zip() method on them, is there a way to invoke this method as part of the stream just after the creation of each object (and to have these objects thrown away immediately after the zip() method has been invoked on them) rather than first having to create a map?

Comment: I think you're going to have to use an intermediate map if you want to do any kind of grouping...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want the 4-argument `Collector#of` which uses a finisher.

Note that `f -> {return new Facet(f); }` can be written as `Facet::new`

```
ConcurrentMap<String, Zipper> zippers = list.parallelStream()
    .map(Facet::new)
    .collect( 
        Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(
            Facet::getZip,
            Collector.of( Zipper::new, 
                Zipper::accept, 
                (a,b)-> {a.combine(b); return a; },
                z -> {z.zip(); return z;}
            )
        )
    );
```